# Is Static link of DLL (using *.lib) possible from code only (without add to project, something like #pragma link "...")?

Tags: syntax, c++builder

I am upgrading my preexisting **CAD/CAM** project (quite big one > 10MByte of code) and have to add some special measuring equipment. The problem is I have more than one supplier of the measuring system (although is already decided which one to use) and I want to configure them (using `#define` in case vendor is changed in future) with code to use only selected device type. So I have something like:

```cpp
  #define use_vendor1
//#define use_vendor2
//#define use_vendor3
```

and some of the vendors APIs require their own DLLs so I need for example:

```
Project/Add to project/vendor1.lib
Project/Remove from project/unused_vendor.lib
```

if `use_vendor1` is used ... That will be uncomfortable to add/remove each type reconfiguration of exe is required. I was wondering if there exist a way similar to this:

```cpp
#ifdef use_vendor1
#pragme link "vendor1.lib"
#endif
```

That one does not work of coarse because DLL `*.lib` is not compiled code as `*.obj` ...

Having all the libs in the project is an option but that would require shipping exe with all the DLL's which I would rather avoid.

Another option would be dynamic DLL link but I rather avoid it as that is more coding for me in it...

I am bound to old **BDS2006 Turbo C++ Explorer** IDE and compiler.

Also is it possible to statically link DLL in relative path to EXE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`#pragma comment`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pragma_comment):

```cpp
#ifdef use_vendor1
#pragma comment(lib, "vendor1.lib")
#endif
```