# Fade2D library & C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I wish to use Fade2D library in my C++Builder projects.

Libraries are in MS Visual Studio's and using them raised an exception:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error contains invalid OMF record, type 0x21 (possibly COFF)
```

I tried the two tools from Embarcadero to build the .lib file for C++ Builder:

- COFF2OMF to convert the .lib from VS format and
- IMPLIB to produces the .lib file starting form DLL

In both cases I have the error:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'GEOM_FADE2D::setLic(const char *, const char *, const char *, const char *, const char *)' referenced from MAIN.OBJ
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved external link errors with generated DLL in Embarcadero C++ Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726637/unresolved-external-link-errors-with-generated-dll-in-embarcadero-c-builder)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately none of the methods shown worked

Comment: are you using implib from your C++ builder installation? if not try it. the dll functions names are mangled how? did you tried all 8 combinations of switches? is the DLL win32 bit?  is the generated lib file meaningful (not just 1024 bytes "empty" file) is your app win32 bit? are you staticly linking the DLL using correct lib file? beware you have to chose correct lib extention while choosing file (IIRC there where 2 *.lib formats one is for DLL and one is some static lib like *.obj that one will not work). ... is the DLL correct? did you try dynamic linking?